# Printing entered string using pointer manipulation

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I am new to pointers, please let me know how can i print the entered character.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

   int main()
   {
      char *ptr;
      ptr = malloc(32 * sizeof(char));
      *ptr = 'h';
      ptr++;
      *ptr = 'e';
      ptr++; 
      *ptr = 'l';
      ptr++;
      *ptr = 'l';
      ptr++;
      *ptr = 'o';
      ptr++;
      *ptr = '\n';

      printf("value entered is %s\n", ptr);

      return 0;
    }
```

I want to print hello

Comment: Two issues: When you print `ptr` is no longer pointing to the original location; And `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. This null-terminator is incredibly important for all string handling (including using `printf` with the `%s` format) to know where the string ends.

Comment: Don't increment the original pointer. Have a temporary pointer point at `ptr` right after malloc, then do all arithmetic on the temporary pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the null-terminator. Add this:

```
ptr++;
*ptr = '\0';
```

Also, the pointer is now pointing to the null-terminator (or previously the newline character). You have to set it back to point to the `'h'` again:

```
ptr -= 6;
```

And when you're done, you should free the memory:

```
free(ptr);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should fix your code like this, with a temporary pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
  char* ptr;
  ptr = malloc(32 * sizeof(char));
  if(ptr == NULL)
  {
    puts("Allocation failed");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  char* tmp = ptr;

  *tmp = 'h';
  tmp++;
  *tmp = 'e';
  tmp++; 
  *tmp = 'l';
  tmp++;
  *tmp = 'l';
  tmp++;
  *tmp = 'o';
  tmp++;
  *tmp = '\0'; // NOTE: null termination not \n

  printf("value entered is %s\n", ptr);
  free(ptr);    

  return 0;
}
```

A proper version without messy pointer arithmetic looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
  char* ptr;
  ptr = malloc(32 * sizeof(char));
  if(ptr == NULL)
  {
    puts("Allocation failed");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  strcpy(ptr, "hello");
  printf("value entered is %s\n", ptr);
  free(ptr);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @TiyaDSoftwareDeveloper What do you mean?

Comment: before free() add ptr = NULL; For making sure pointer is not containing any data, which can be junk in future.

Comment: setting a pointer after free? Sorry but that will throw invalid pointer error, as the memory you have u freed and trying to make pointer null.
Please correct me if I m wrong

Comment: @TiyaDSoftwareDeveloper Yeah, either I don't understand you or everything you say is wrong. To begin with, the pointer itself is not stored on the heap...

Comment: True,  pointer itself is not stored on the heap. So, once you freed, no sense of making it NULL(ptr = NULL), its now beyond your scope.

Comment: @TiyaDSoftwareDeveloper It's very common practice to set pointers to NULL after freeing them, to allow allocation functions like `free(ptr); ptr = malloc(...)` that free() up old data and can be called at any point, regardless of whether the pointer is pointing to allocated memory or not. This is taking advantage of `free(NULL)` being a no-op. Anyway, this isn't the place for this discussion.

Comment: thanks for correcting me. Will remember this in future

Answer (score 0):

You can, rather using the `malloc()` function, use the `calloc()` function, which achieves the same goal of `malloc()`, but fills the memory with '\0'. This makes it easier to play with non-fixed length strings. 
You can find the documentation of this function  [here](https://fr.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc).

Here is the code I've made :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char *ptr;
  ptr = calloc(32,sizeof(char));
  *ptr = 'h';
  ptr++;
  *ptr = 'e';
  ptr++; 
  *ptr = 'l';
  ptr++;
  *ptr = 'l';
  ptr++;
  *ptr = 'o';
  ptr++;
  *ptr = '\0';  //It should be null terminated

  ptr -= 5;
  printf("value entered is %s\n", ptr);

  free(ptr);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: calloc() will increase unnecessary call for initializing ptr with '0'.

Comment: True, but it avoids problems with non-null terminated strings.

Comment: @kiranBiradar Definitely true yes ! But in that case author missed this '\0'...